# Match a line break on the line before another match

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I have a file with the following pattern:

```
A = 1
B = 2
C = 3
A = 10
B = 20
C = 30
```

I would like match only the line break before A = *

My attempt would also matches A = * as well as the line break

Code:

```
[\r\n]+.*A.*
```

But I only need the line break alone. I also understand the first A would get sacrificed as there is no like above it.

Is it possible to use lookbehind?

EDIT:
My attempt works but leave 2 groups which I can just access group 2. I was hoping to get this done in only 1 group

```
([.*\r\n])(.*A.*)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you are trying to split the string into ABC groups. Look for a `\n` with a lookahead = 'A'

```
text = """\
A = 1
B = 2
C = 3
A = 10
B = 20
C = 30
"""

re.split(r"\n(?=A)", text)
```

Returns:

```
['A = 1\nB = 2\nC = 3', 'A = 10\nB = 20\nC = 30\n']
```

If you want the actual newline, use the same pattern with `re.search()` or `re.finditer()` to get the match object(s).

Comment: Looks like I had misinterpreted the question, this is the way to go ;)

Answer (score 0):

$[\s]+^ works in Adobe brackets, every RegExp editor is different, but I would generally try using the $ (end of line) and ^ (beginning of line) combined with \s which is any whitespace including new lines to match what you want.

Edit:

Try this for the lookahead:

($\s*)?^(?=A)

Comment: Thank you! but Im interested the line break itself and not variable A

Comment: Modified to use a lookahead instead.  This works for me without needing to replace the A.